# Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<XmlResult>. Actual:<XmlResult>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

I'm new in unit testing so may be I do something wrong.

I have some XmlResult class:

```
public class XmlResult : ActionResult
    {
        public XmlDocument Document { private get; set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
```

Also I have controller extension method:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
    {
        public static XmlResult Xml(this Controller controller, XmlDocument document)
        {
            return new XmlResult { Document = document };
        }
    }
```

And a test method:

```
[TestClass]
    public class ControllerExtensionsTests
    {
        #region Xml
        [TestMethod]
        public void XmlExtensionShouldReturnCorrectValue()
        {
            // Arrange
            var mockRepository = new Mock<T>();
            var productsController = new ProductController(mockProductRepository.Object);

            var someXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

            // Act
            var actual = productsController.Xml(someXmlDocument);
            var expected = new XmlResult { Document = someXmlDocument };

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);               
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

And whe I call `Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);`  my test is failed with message `"Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<XmlResult>. Actual:<XmlResult>."`. What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Expected and result will be different instances of XmlResult, so they won't be equal.

Comment: Then why when I create two different instances of Xmlresult like: `var expected = new XmlResult { Document = someXmlDocument };
 var actual = new XmlResult { Document = someXmlDocument };` test passes??

Comment: `productsController.Xml(someXmlDocument);` is also creating of new instance of XmlResult, but just in another method

Comment: Inlining the .Xml call shouldn't change anything, so there must be something else going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add an override equals method on your xml result class and do your own implementation for the equals comparison.

Something like below....

```
public class XmlResult : ActionResult
{
    public XmlDocument Document { private get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        //Do something
    }

    public bool Equals(XmlResult other)
    {
        if(ReferenceEquals(null, other))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return Equals(other.Document, Document);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Document != null ? Document.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```